# Корректная реализация алгоритма поиска элемента в массиве с использованием CUDA

Tags: c, массивы, распараллеливание, cuda

Доброго времени суток. Имеется следующая задача:

> Имеется `NUM_VALUE` элементов (пусть они будут находиться в массиве
>   `inArray` типа `int`) и некий массив `baseArray`, состоящий из `ARR_SIZE`
>   элементов типа `int`. Необходимо для каждого элемента из массива `inArray`
>   выполнить функцию `func()` (для простоты положим, что это некоторая
>   бинарная операция) и проверить, имеется ли результирующее значение в
>   массиве `baseArray`. Если имеется, то увеличить счётчик на единицу. В
>   итоге, на выходе необходимо число "попаданий"(значение счётчика).

Естественно, размеры массивов достаточно велики, чтобы эта задача выполнялась очень долго без распараллеливания. Я ознакомился с технологией CUDA и решил, что она идеально подходит для решения подобной задачи. К сожалению, я новичок в ней, и поэтому смогу накидать лишь идею реализации.

Пусть, к примеру, `NUM_VALUE` 16, а `ARR_SIZE` - 16384 (2^14). Тогда каждый элемент из массива `inArray` будем ассоциировать с отдельным блоком (т.е. присвоем ему номер `blockIdx.x`), и тогда нити каждого блока будут применять вышеоговоренную функцию `func` к этому одному элементу.

Помогите советом, как можно улучшить сам процесс расспараллеливания и, если возможно, примером кода (а то все примеры, которые я изучал, были больно простыми).

Если что, у меня

```
GeForce GT730M
Compute Capability 3.5
Global Memory 2 GB
Shared Memory Per Block 48 KB
Max Threads Per Block 1024
Number of multiprocessors 2
Max Threads Dim 1024 : 1024 : 64
Max Grid Dim 2*(10 ^ 9) : 65535 : 65535
```