# неожиданный вылет программы

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, память

Программа неожиданно вылетает при запуске. Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define G_SIZE (int)pow((double)2,(double)22)
#define T_SIZE (int)pow((double)2,(double)14)
#define PROGRESS_BAR_VALUE 52428

int main()
{
    int *g_arr;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));

    g_arr = (int*)malloc(G_SIZE * T_SIZE * sizeof(int));
    memset(g_arr, 0, G_SIZE * T_SIZE * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < G_SIZE; i++) {
        k++;
        if (k >= PROGRESS_BAR_VALUE) {
            k = 0;
            printf("%c", 219);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        for (j = 0; j < T_SIZE; j++) {
            *(g_arr + i*T_SIZE + j) = rand();
        }
    }
    printf("Press any key...");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Сменил в `T_SIZE` показатель степени на `2` - нормально отработала. Я так понимаю, проблема вся в некорректном выделении памяти, но я до конца не уверен.

**Примечание**. Пытаюсь решить следующую [задачу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767745/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-cuda).

Comment: 256 ГиБ пямяти!? зачем? В лучшем случае malloc провалится, в худшем — только при исчерпании доступной памяти в системе процесс умрёт.

Comment: Где именно вылетает? Что показала отладка?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, собственно, с такими данными приходится иметь дело. Если интересно, я пытаюсь решить задачу, представленную в примечании (сейчас добавлю) только в последовательном варианте.

Comment: @AnT, ды собственно, до отладки с F10 или F11 даже дело не доходит - просто вылет

Answer (score 6):

Операция умножения в С ассоциативна слева-направо. Ваши вычисления

```
G_SIZE * T_SIZE * sizeof(int)
```

интерпретируются компилятором как

```
(G_SIZE * T_SIZE) * sizeof(int)
```

Так как ваши `G_SIZE` и `T_SIZE` имеют тип `int`, первое умножение будет происходить в домене типа `int`, который сразу переполнится (при 32-битном `int`). Поведение не определено. Возьмите в привычку выполнять вычисления размеров памяти в домене типа `size_t`. (Подразумевая, что речь идет о 64-битной платформе с 64-битным `size_t`.)

В остальном - все работает нормально, при условии, что платформа в состоянии выделить такое количество памяти. И медленно, разумеется.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я так понимаю, память тут оперативная имеется ввиду?

Comment: @Setplus: Зависит от того, присутствует ли у вас своп-файл. Если у вас в системе не отключен своп-файл, то оперативная память не имеет никакого значения (влияет только на скорость). Важен именно максимальный размер своп-файла.

Comment: В моем случае код работает на Win10 x64 машине с 128GB RAM. 128GB - это, конечно, немало, но все равно намного меньше, чем вы запрашиваете в своем примере.

Comment: ещё раз спасибо!